# inject css into a crossdomain local iframe

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I am embeding an iframe that uses another port.
I need to inject a css in the iframe but Chrome doesn't let me because of security.
Can I lose the rules so the injection work?
My problem is only when localhost.
Production everything is in the same domain/port using nginx reverse proxy, so no problem there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Comment: @dgknca no because even thought the iframe is in localhost, it uses another port. So when I try to inject the css, chrome doesn't let it happen because of security.

Comment: To access using js: You have to redirect the content from a server allowing CORS. Or alter the page server side directly.